# How to implement counting sort (O(n)) using list in OCaml?

Tags: sorting, functional-programming, ocaml

`Counting sort` uses array and can have O(n) performance if the numbers being sorted are within a known range.

But is it possible to implement counting sort using `list` only in OCaml?

My intuitive is that it is possible to simulate `counting sort` using `list` and `map` without using mutable arrays, but the performance would not be O(n).

If so, does `counting sort` really help OCaml application with anything under the context of not using mutable things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that, yes, it is not possible to implement O(n) counting sort without arrays. What are you asking?

Comment: i am asking `If so, does counting sort really help OCaml application with anything under the context of not using mutable things?`